# Cache-control no-cache but not on child folders in Nginx

Tags: nginx, proxy, cache

I'm using this rule in Nginx

```
location ~ /app/(?<code>...)/acme/?(?<uri>.*) {
  add_header Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
  proxy_pass http://int-srv/$code/acme/dev/$uri;
}
```

This adds the Cache-control header I wrote above on calls to

```
/app/abc/acme
/app/abc/acme/assets
/app/abc/acme/assets/js
/app/abc/acme/assets/css
/app/abc/acme/anything
```

I only want the Cache-control header to be applied to /app/abc/acme because when this endpoint is called, the response is the contents of our index.html. I don't want to cache it and it's currently working great.

If you're thinking of making the rule using index.html, unfortunately, it won't work because I don't see we're making a call directly to the file (/app/abc/acme/index.html) in chrome debugger tools

So basically this is what I want

```
/app/abc/acme - apply cache-control no-cache,etc header to this location only
/app/abc/acme/assets - don't want cache-control header
/app/abc/acme/assets/js - don't want cache-control header
/app/abc/acme/assets/css - don't want cache-control header
/app/abc/acme/anything - - don't want cache-control header
```

If you think I'm doing something bad, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use two locations, one matching the shorter URL. For example:

```
location ~ ^/app(?<code>/...)/acme/(?<stuff>.*)$ {
    add_header Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
    rewrite ^ $code/acme/dev/$stuff break;
    proxy_pass http://int-srv;
}
location ~ ^/app(?<code>/...)/acme$ {
    rewrite ^ $code/acme/dev break;
    proxy_pass http://int-srv;
}
```

The variable name `$uri` is already defined by the system, so you should probably use a different name.

Using a URI component with the `proxy_pass` directive when inside a regular expression location clearly works, but is undocumented. In fact, [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) states:

> When location is specified using a regular expression. In this case,
>   the directive should be specified without a URI

So my example uses the `rewrite ... break` instead.

Comment: oh, just noticed, why did you put slash after <code>?

Comment: No particular reason - one less character to type in the rewrite statement. Moved from outside of the capture.